# What matches this regex?

Tags: c#, regex

This compiles and executes:

```
 var re = new Regex(@"what\ever");
```

But I can't find anything that matches it. `whatever`, `what\ever` and `what\\ever` all fail to match.

`\e` isn't a valid escape sequence AFAIK, so I'm not sure what the intended behaviour here is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `\e` matches the "Escape" character (ASCII code 27). Hence it should match `"what\x1bver"`

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Escape Sequences".

Answer (score 3):

\e is the escape control character

you can use a free tool called [The Regulator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/) which has built in intellisense which helps for things like this.

Answer (score 2):

`\e` is usually equal to `\033`.

Comment: Correct... but who uses octal?

Comment: @Mark: People who prefer keeping their fingers on the number row instead of reaching around for those pesky letters :P

Answer (score 2):

It's the escape sequence (0x1B).

See non printable characters section [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use

```
var re = new Regex(@"[what\ever]");
```

to match "what\ever"

Comment: That looks like a character class to me.... not at all what I want. That will match *anything* with 1 or more of those letters in it. Not to mention this was only an example... I have no intention of matching `what\ever` (if I did, I'd use `what\\ever`)

Comment: `-1` for giving a wrong answer. [See this explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Bwhat%5Cever%5D)